# How to know that bootstrap plugin has been initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement to validator.js plugin for bootstrap found here : 
https://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

I want to hook into the submit event.

The following is written in the documentation for the plugin : "Be sure your submit handler is bound after the plugin has been initialized on your form"

I have written my submit handler like this and everything seems to work fine.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        console.log("invalid form");
      } else {
        console.log("everything looks good!");
      }
    })
});
```

But can I be sure that this will work all the time?

How can I be sure that the plugin has already been initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is ready, because of:

```
$(document).ready(function(){...});
```

If you want load your functions after entire page (images or iframes) not just the DOM is ready use:

```
$(window).on("load", function(){...})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. So when have the plugin been initialized? In document.ready or on("load)?

Comment: @Thomas Document ready runs after all assets are loaded, so the plugin  is fully loaded when your function is called.